# Как поднять через вверх элементы как на макете ? Через флекс

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
body {
    padding: 100px 75px 101px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#2d2d2d;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
}
.header {
    margin: 12px 403px 52px 3px;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 65px;
    font-weight: 700;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

p {
    width: 1092px;
    margin: 0px 73px 30px 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 33px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.middle-section {
    width: 1088px;
    height: 583px;
    margin: 57px 150px 54px 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
.text-style {
    font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
    width: 445px;
    margin: 20px 264px 26px 1px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
}

img {
    width: 1095px;
    height: 560px;
    margin: 52px 143px 57px 0;
}
.advertising-stambul {
    background-image: url('./img/stambul.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    margin: 0 0 0 auto; 
    padding: 185px 155px 43px 30px;
    font-family: Lato;
    color: #fff;
}

.advertising-stambul-title {
    width: 346px;
    height: 67px;
    margin: 0 0 18px 1px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}

.advertising-stambul-text{
    width: 298px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 18px 49px 0 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.advertising-duster{
    background-image: url('./img/Duster.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:auto;
    margin: 0 0 0 auto; 
    padding: 224px 144px 43px 29px;
    font-family: Lato;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
}

.advertising-duster-title{
    width: 356px;
    height: 23px;
    margin: 0 0 23px 3px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.3;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}

.advertising-duster-text{
    word-break:break-all;
    width: 334px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 23px 25px 0 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}

main {
    float: left
}



.advertising-stambul, .advertising-duster {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    width: 532px;
    height: 328px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>OnlineShop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main class="main">
        <section class="section">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="header">Как ухаживать за обувью из кожи</h1>
                <p>
                    Материала для обуви лучше натуральной кожи все ещё не придумали. Качественную кожу очень приятно носить, 
                    она идеально ложится по ноге, в нужных местах немного растягивается. 
                    В кожаной обуви, если она соответствует погоде, создаётся хороший микроклимат – ноги не мёрзнут, не потеют,
                    и чувствуют себя очень комфортно.
                    Неудивительно, что по статистике больше 60% покупателей выбирает обувь именно из гладкой натуральной кожи. 
                    Вдобавок кожа практична и не требует трудоёмкого ухода. 
                </p>
                <p>
                    Но это совсем не означает, что можно раз в полгода протереть обувь тряпочкой и на этом остановиться. 
                    Так же, как кожа лица и тела, материал обуви нуждается в заботе. 
                    Регулярный уход надолго продлит срок службы любимой пары и сделает
                    её аккуратной и сияющей, словно только что из магазина.
                </p>
                <ul>
                    <li> 
                        На что стоит обратить внимание перед покупкой
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Перед тем, как надеть обувь в превый раз
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Ежедневный уход за кожанной обувью в домашних условиях
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <img  src="./img/shous.jpg"  alt="Замшевые ботинки">
            </div>
            <div class="middle-section">
                <span class="text-style">На что стоит обратить внимание перед покупкой</span>
                <p>
                    Подбирайте обувь точно по размеру и полноте. 
                    Слишкам тесная обувь черезмерно растягивается 
                    и кожа испортится,не говоря уже о дискомфорте. 
                    А если модель сидит слишком свободно, то при ходьбе 
                    на ней начнут образовываться складки и заломы.
                </p>
                <span  class="text-style">Перед тем, как надеть обувь в превый раз</span>
                <p>
                    Перед первой ноской для новой пары нужно подобрать водо- или грязеоттакивающее средство,
                    подхлдящее для натуральной кожи, и обработать кожу в соответсвии с инструкцией. 
                    После высыхания - чистить кремом.
                </p>
                <span class="text-style">Ежедневный уход за кожаной обувью в домашних условиях</span>
                <p>
                    Лучше всего заняться обувью после возвращения домой. 
                    Если этого не сделать, то со временем появляются трудновыводимые пятна,
                    портится цвет кожи, образуются трещены.
                </p>
                <p>
                    После каждого выхода на улицу протирайте обувь сухой салфеткой,
                    если на коже только пыль, или вложной тряпкой - в случае сильного
                    загрязнения. Начинайте мыть с каблука, затем очистите подошву,после
                    этого - материал верха. После мытья нужно как следует протереть пару мягкой тканью,
                    чтобы избавить от лишней влаги. Иначе обувь будетсушиться очень долго.
                </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                <img src="./img/brush.jpg" alt="средства для чистки обуви">
                <p>
                    Второй этап-сушка.
                    Ни в коем случае не используйте источники тепла - батарею, 
                    обогреватель, фен с горячим воздухом. 
                    Да,они сушат быстро, но за это приходит расплата в виде
                    задубевшей покоробившейся кожи. Нужно вытащить стельки,
                    набить обувь бумагой либо положить внутрь формодержатель
                    и сушить при комнатной температуре. Тогда ваши туфли или сапоги 
                    надолго сохранят красивую форму
                    без заломов. сушка дляться довольно долго, и по этому не 
                    рекомендуется носить одну и ту же пару каждый день. 
                    Обувь и подкладка должны отдохнуть и расправиться, только тогда вам будет комфортно и тепло.
                </p>
                <p>
                    И наконец-крем.
                    Сухую и чистую пару нужно обработать кремом, чтобы кожа оставалась 
                    эластичной,мягкой и блестящей. Наносите крем тоненьким слоем с помощью
                    обувной щетки и аккуратно распределите по всейповерхности
                    Затем через несколько часов, когда крем впитается, сотрите остатки сухой салфеткой
                    отпалируйте кожу мягкой тряпочкой.
                    Крем подбирается точно в цвет обуви, поэтому стоит задуматься
                    еще перед покупкой, каким уходовым средством вы будете пользоваться.<br>
                    В магазине легко подобрать черный, коричневый и самый универсальный-
                    бесцветный крем, есть и другие цвета, где бывает сложно найти нужный оттенок.<br>
                    По мере необходимости дополнительно обрабатывайте пару водотталкивающими спреями
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <aside>
        <div class="advertising-stambul">
            <span class="advertising-stambul-title">
                Горящие туры в Стамбул от 20 000руб
            </span>
            <span class="advertising-stambul-text">
                Окунись в настоящую восточную сказку
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="advertising-duster">
            <span class="advertising-duster-title"> Новый Renault Duster</span>
            <span class="advertising-duster-text">Легендарный внедорожник в новом дизайне</span>
        </div>
    </aside>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Вам соит почитать в принципе, что такое flex сначала, а потом задавать вопросы. Это основа верстки сейчас.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.d-flex{
  display: flex;
}
.w-100{
  width: 100%;
}
main{
  width: 80%;
}
aside{
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <main>
    main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main main 
  </main>
  <aside>
    aside aside aside aside aside aside aside aside aside 
  </aside>
</div>
```